# Ordering a ConcurrentDictionary. Why is this not working?

Tags: c#, concurrency, parallel-processing, concurrentdictionary, parallel.for

We have a C# app that populates tables on worksheets within an Excel document.

The tables must be populated in the order the rows are returned from the database.

The object DataFileColData is defined as a List and contains the result set rows. For testing purposes, I'm only using [0] of the List.

Code segment #1 below doesn't work. Row order is not preserved in that the end result has the data displayed out of order although the numbers themselves are listed in order:

```
if (DataFileColData[0].Count() > 0)
{
    ConcurrentDictionary<int, DataRow> theRows = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, DataRow>(9, DataFileColData[0].Count());

    Parallel.For(0, DataFileColData[0].Count(), i =>
    {
        // go through each column
        int c = 0;
        try
        {
            foreach (var Col in DataFileColData)
            {
                var cell = Col[i];
                if (cell != null)
                {
                    if (cell.GetType().Name == "JArray") //If Jarray then table compression was used not column compression
                    {
                        if (theRows.TryAdd(i, Dt.NewRow()))
                            theRows[i].ItemArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object[]>(Col[i].ToString());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (theRows.TryAdd(i, Dt.NewRow()))
                            theRows[i][c] = cell;
                    }
                }
                c++;
            }
        } //try
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("Exception thrown in \"PublicMethods.cs | RenderExcelFile\" while in foreach loop over DataFileColData: " + e.ToString());
        }

    } //for
    ); //parallel

    //Add the rows to the datatable in their original order
    //(might have gotten skewed from the parallel.for loop)
    for (int x = 0; x < theRows.Count; x++)
        Dt.Rows.Add(theRows[x]);

    //Set the name so it appears nicely in the Excel Name Box dropdown instead of "table1", "table2", etc etc.
    Dt.TableName = ExcelTableSpec.TableTitle + " " + r.TableID;
}
```

code segment #2 below does work with the row order and data associated with each row preserved :

```
if (DataFileColData[0].Count() > 0)
{
    DataRow[] theRows = new DataRow[DataFileColData[0].Count()];

    Parallel.For(0, DataFileColData[0].Count(), i =>
    {
        DataRow Rw = Dt.NewRow();

        // go through each column
        int c = 0;
        try
        {
            foreach (var Col in DataFileColData)
            {
                var cell = Col[i];
                if (cell != null)
                {
                    if (cell.GetType().Name == "JArray") //If Jarray then table compression was used not column compression
                    {
                        lock (theRows)
                        {
                            theRows[i] = Dt.NewRow();
                            theRows[i].ItemArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object[]>(Col[i].ToString());
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lock (theRows)
                        {
                            theRows[i] = Dt.NewRow();
                            theRows[i][c] = cell;
                        }
                    }
                }
                c++;
            }
        } //try
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("Exception thrown in \"PublicMethods.cs | RenderExcelFile\" while in foreach loop over DataFileColData: " + e.ToString());
        }

    } //for
    ); //parallel

    //Add the rows to the datatable in their original order
    //(might have gotten skewed from the parallel.for loop)
    Dt = theRows.CopyToDataTable();

    //Set the name so it appears nicely in the Excel Name Box dropdown instead of "table1", "table2", etc etc.
    Dt.TableName = ExcelTableSpec.TableTitle + " " + r.TableID;
}
```

I don't understand why. I didn't think the locking mechanism would be needed because each thread gets its own instance of "i" and a ConcurrentDictionary is supposed to be thread safe.

Would someone be able to explain to me please why the code isn't working the way I think it should?

Thank you!

---

**UPDATED CODE as per @Enigmativity's comments below.**

The MSDN documentation isn't quite clear (to me anyway), but does appear to update the DataTable even though the MSDN documentation doesn't indicate it does when executing the NewRow() method.

New working code below:

```
if (DataFileColData[0].Count() > 0)
                {
                    DataRow[] theRows = new DataRow[DataFileColData[0].Count()];

                    Parallel.For(0, DataFileColData[0].Count(), i =>
                    //for (int i = 0; i < DataFileColData[0].Count(); i++)
                    {
                        lock (Dt)
                        {
                            theRows[i] = Dt.NewRow();
                        }

                        // go through each column
                        int c = 0;
                        try
                        {
                            foreach (var Col in DataFileColData)
                            {
                                var cell = Col[i];
                                if (cell != null)
                                {
                                    if (cell.GetType().Name == "JArray") //If Jarray then table compression was used not column compression
                                    {
                                        theRows[i].ItemArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object[]>(Col[i].ToString());
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        theRows[i][c] = cell;
                                    }
                                }
                                c += 1;
                            } //foreach
                        } //try
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            throw new Exception("Exception thrown in \"PublicMethods.cs | RenderExcelFile\" while in foreach loop over DataFileColData: " + e.ToString());
                        }

                    } //for
                    ); //parallel

                    //Add the rows to the datatable in their original order
                    //(might have gotten skewed from the parallel.for loop)
                    Dt = theRows.CopyToDataTable();

                    //Set the name so it appears nicely in the Excel Name Box dropdown instead of "table1", "table2", etc etc.
                    Dt.TableName = ExcelTableSpec.TableTitle + " " + r.TableID;

                    //cleanup
                    if (theRows != null)
                        Array.Clear(theRows, 0, theRows.Length);
                    theRows = null;

                } //if (DataFileColData[0].Count() > 0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the documentation for ([MSDN Data Tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable%28VS.71%29.aspx)).

The key point is:

> Thread Safety
>
> This type is safe for multithreaded read operations. You must
>   synchronize any write operations.

So it's not `i` the the `ConcurrentDictionary` causing your issues.

---

I've decompiled the `NewRow` method and there is a call to `NewRow(int record)`. This code clearly shows write operations.

```
internal DataRow NewRow(int record)
{
  if (-1 == record)
    record = this.NewRecord(-1);
  this.rowBuilder._record = record;
  DataRow row = this.NewRowFromBuilder(this.rowBuilder);
  this.recordManager[record] = row;
  if (this.dataSet != null)
    this.DataSet.OnDataRowCreated(row);
  return row;
}
```

Comment: I'm confused because I'm not actually adding to the DataTable until outside the Parallel.For loop; only new DataRows are created and added to the ConcurrentDictionary with the DataTable schema, which doesn't change. When I add rows to the DataTable, it's in a single threaded for-loop, so there shouldn't be any threading issues with that.

Comment: @FreeCoder24 - I took the `Dt.NewRow();` calls to be the issue. They are in the `For.Parallel` and they are a write operation.

Comment: looking at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.newrow(v=vs.110).aspx), it says, "You must use the NewRow method to create new DataRow objects with the same schema as the DataTable. After creating a DataRow, you can add it to the DataRowCollection, through the DataTable object's Rows property" which means it's not altering the DataTable. The new datarow object is then added to the specific key in the ConcurrentDictionary, and only that specific key (I). Thus, the thread where I=2 shouldn't be altering the datarow on the thread where I=109. Is this not true??

Comment: @FreeCoder24 - It may not be altering the `DataTime`, but it is clearly doing internal assignments - `this.rowBuilder._record = record;` && `this.recordManager[record] = row;`. I wouldn't trust this operation to be thread-safe.

Comment: @FreeCoder24 - Why are you trying to multi-thread this anyway? How long does it take on a single thread?

Comment: the whole process takes several minutes depending on how many rows and columns are returned. This loop is a big chunk of time when there's several thousand records: around 25 seconds. With the parallel this portion is now down to around 15 seconds. I'm going to mark this as the answer as I've rewritten the code taking your comments into account and it appears to be correct despite what MSDN says. Thank you for taking the time to reverse engineer the NewRow method to see the internals.